# Store disc images on a hard drive

Tags: windows-7, mount, iso-image, compression

I'm cleaning up around my computer (A Win7 ultimate machine), and part of my plan is to rip all my program CDs and store them on a dedicated 1TB hard drive. My initial plan was to simply dump the discs into ISOs and then virtually mount the image when needed.

However, several of my programs are huge (in the 6-8gb range) and I've begun trying to find a way to compress these images while still retaining the mountability. Built in NTFS compression produced a savings of 50mb on a 4gb ISO... hardly substantial!

I'm now looking for other archive formats that can be compressed and still virtually mounted. Performance of the mount is not so important as the images are only used once a year or so. However, I'd like the archive to use as little space as possible. I'd also like to find a free solution, if possible. I checked into WinMount but they have limits on the archive size that precludes its use.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Most programs are already compressed do trying to compress compress files is pointless

Comment: @Ramhound These are disc images though... My understanding is that CDs don't employ compression?

Comment: You said program disk.  A program is compressed into a variety of formats normally CAB files

Comment: The thing that Ramhound is trying to say is that CD images already contain content that is highly compressed (in most cases). Media can't be compressed and binaries are already heavily compressed as well. Unless you store a lot of text files on your iso's, you're not going to be much better off. The time and effort that you put in it will cost you more than an extra disk to store your images.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, right. I see now (and boy do I feel stupid). If you want to answer, I'll mark it as accepted.